# How to avoid massive overhead of Sleuth Slf4J integration

Tags: performance, spring-cloud, slf4j, spring-cloud-sleuth

In our Spring Boot application (2.0.4.RELEASE), we use Zipkin to integrate distributed tracing.

When creating the integration manually with a 10% sampling rate, meaning with a `@Configuration` like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ZipkinConfiguration {
    @Value("${grpc.zipkin.endpoint:}")
    private String zipkinEndpoint;
    @Bean
    public SpanCustomizer currentSpanCustomizer(Tracing tracing) {
        return CurrentSpanCustomizer.create(tracing);
    }
    @Bean
    public Tracing tracing(@Value("${spring.application.name}") String serviceName) {
        return Tracing.newBuilder().localServiceName(serviceName).spanReporter(spanReporter()).build();
    }

    private Reporter<Span> spanReporter() {
        return AsyncReporter.create(sender());
    }

    private Sender sender() {
        return OkHttpSender.create(zipkinEndpoint);
    }
}
```

our application has a 50 percentile performance of about 19ms and a 99.9 percentile of about 90ms at around 10 requests per second.

When integrating Sleuth 2.0.2.RELEASE instead like this in gradle:

```
compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:2.0.2.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin:2.0.2.RELEASE"
```

the performance drops massively to a p50 of 49ms and a p999 of 120ms.

I tried disabling the different parts of the Sleuth integration (`spring.sleuth.async.enabled`, `spring.sleuth.reactor.enabled`, etc.).

Disabling all these integrations brings the performance to p50: 25ms, p999: 103 ms. *Just having Sleuth adds about 15-25% of overhead.*

It turns out that the one thing with the significant impact is setting `spring.sleuth.log.slf4j.enabled` to `false`. If all other integrations are enabled, but this is disabled, the performance stays within the Sleuth overhead mentioned above, although nothing is logged.

So my question is:
Is there a way to avoid the overhead by Sleuth (compared to "manual" tracing) and especially the one done by the SLF4J integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is to disable Slf4j integration as you mentioned. When a new span / scope is created, we go through Slf4j to put data in MDC and it takes time unfortunately. Disabling that will save it.

Comment: Thank you, this is what we did and as mentioned it improves the situation massively. But Sleuth still adds quite more overhead than I would have expected. But I have seen that there are some bigger changes with respect to performance for the upcoming 2.1.0 release, I am looking forward to those and will let you know once we can switch to 2.1.0!

Comment: Definitely, check the snapshots out cause in terms of reactive you should see plenty of changes. If you want to help, you can always put a breakpoint in the slf4j component and verify which other component delegates to it the most. That would be very helpful.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but migrating to 2.1 requires some more changes on our side. Once this is done I will try to remember doing this debugging - if the problem still exists ;-)